# Java: case expressions must be constant expressions

Tags: java

I am using enum with values and when I try to use `SmartCard.MessageType.SC_CONN.getValue()` in the switch case I am getting the error

> case expressions must be constant expressions

```
public class SmartCard {
    public enum MessageType {
        /** 0x00 Acknowledge of message */
        SC_ACKP(0),
        /** 0x01 Connect to the smart card */
        SC_CONN(1),
        /** 0x02 Request ATR attributes of smart card */
        SC_ATTR(2),
        /** 0x03 Send data to smart card */
        SC_SEND(3);

        private int value;

        MessageType(int value) {
            this.value = value;
        }


        public int getValue() {
            return this.value;
        }

    };

    }

public class TCPServer {

public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception {
      }
    private static void handleMessage(int packetType, int dataLen, byte[] receiveMessage, Socket clientSocket,
            SmartCard smartCard) {
        ByteBuffer answerBuffer = null;
        int value = SmartCard.MessageType.SC_CONN.getValue();
        String preferredProtocol = "";
        switch (packetType) {
        case 0:
            break;
        case value:
            break;
        case 2: 

        }

    }
}
```

Comment: `case value:` is the problem, you can't have a variable in case statement.

Answer (score 2):

In Java, the case statements must be a compile time constant, and `value` isn't, it's assigned at runtime.

Comment: should be a comment.

Comment: @jackjay I disagree.  This definitely answers the question.  If anything, _your_ comment should have been an answer.

Answer (score 1):

The second case of the switch statement is written wrongly. `value` cannot be used here. The value of every case must be constant. Let's see what the JLS says.

[Section 14.11](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-14.html#jls-14.11)

```
SwitchStatement:
    switch ( Expression ) SwitchBlock

SwitchBlock:
    { SwitchBlockStatementGroupsopt SwitchLabelsopt }

SwitchBlockStatementGroups:
    SwitchBlockStatementGroup
    SwitchBlockStatementGroups SwitchBlockStatementGroup

SwitchBlockStatementGroup:
    SwitchLabels BlockStatements

SwitchLabels:
    SwitchLabel
    SwitchLabels SwitchLabel

SwitchLabel:
    case ConstantExpression :
    case EnumConstantName :
    default :

EnumConstantName:
    Identifier
```

Look at the definition for a `SwitchLabel`. The thing after `case` must either be a `ConstantExpression` or an `EnumConstantName`. `value` is neither of those.

One solution to this problem is to use `if...else if...else` statements.

```
if (packetType == 0) {

} else if (packetType == value) {

} else if (packetType == 2) {

}
```

If you really want to keep the switch statement, do an if check in the default branch.

```
switch (packetType) {
case 0:
    break;
case 2: 
    break;
default:
    if (packetType == value) { ... }
    break;
}
```